# Unable to Make Payment via PayPal api into flutter app

Tags: flutter, paypal

We have developed a flutter app (online doctor appointments) and integrated the PayPal payment method into the mobile application. This app is not live yet but we are testing it into production mode and when as a customer, I am going to make the payment the payment not deducted from my account and I have received the email from PayPal support(subject: Your payment to Doc Domi couldn't be sent). As a Product owner unable to receive the payment from the customer's end. Even the customer gets the OTP for the final transaction and once he enters the OTP the payment is successfully done but the amount was not deducted from customer's account.

here is the response that we got it:
PayPal response is {name: COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION, message: Transaction is declined due to compliance violation., information_link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#error-COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION, debug_id: 6caee6baf1599}

We have verified the account and linked the bank account too.

Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: please share you code what you have worked on

Comment: you can mail the PayPal support team by sharing the error message you getting that will more efficient for you.

Comment: What are the countries of the accounts involved? Please do another test and update with a log of the full API request+response.

Comment: Without more information, you'll probably need to contact PayPal -- if this is production, make sure and give a recent example so there will be full logs available